# App data on SD card is lost after uninstall , How can i keep the data?

Tags: android

I saved videos file of application on external storage ( SD card removable) (/App/data/package/files) . When user update or uninstall app folder is removed and lost all videos . I tried options android:allowBackup and android:fullBackupContent but it's not working . I read on home android develop page this options support for auto back up data on the cloud (<25/mb) . How can i do to keep the data ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your data stays after user uninstall's your app , don't save your data in "App/data" path.
save it in ExternalStorageDirectory.
your file path should be :

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/videos");    
myDir.mkdirs();
```

and add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

it doest not guarantee's that your data stays in user's phone forever, but as long as user doesn't manually remove this folder , it stays safe.

Comment: I tried but it not working ! Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() only working on Internal Storage . With SDcard you need use context.getExternalFilesDir() BUT it  returned  path  /storage/9016-4EF8/Android/data/package/ on SD card (removable) . I need save on SD card (REMOVABLE)

Comment: what if users phone does not support sd card?

Comment: and another thing is : The getExternalStorageDirectory method will return the default shared storage, which may or may not be the SD card.

Comment: I checked SD card available before save videos . If not support sd card i use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , it will save videos to path Internal like /storage/emulated/0

Comment: if sdk is available and user manually sets the default storage to sdk then you'll get the sdk location when you call Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ...